# Why is json_decode no working on this json string?

Tags: php

I'm stuck at a problem and I hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

this code:

```
$output = curl_exec($handle);
var_dump(trim($output));
```

returns the following:
string(114) " {"code":0,"description":"Operation Completed","status":"","balance":50.0} "

If I try to decode it like this:

```
$balanceJson = json_decode($output);
echo($balanceJson->balance);
```

I get an error: Trying to get property of non-object, and the object $balanceJson is null

But if I copy the output string and do this, it works fine:

```
$balanceJson = json_decode('{"code":0,"description":"Operation Complete Successfully","status":"","balance":50.0}');
echo($balanceJson->balance);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

```
$balanceJson = json_decode(trim($output)); 
print_r($balanceJson);
```

returns null

Comment: Please post result of two additional tests: 1.) `$balanceJson = json_decode(trim($output));` and 2.) `print_r($balanceJson);`

Comment: There has to be something extra in the string since there are 75 visible characters, not 114.

Comment: The code posted in the question [works fine](https://3v4l.org/tJS4c).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine but probably you have hidden chars blocking you.

```
    if (substr($output, 0, 3) == pack('CCC', 239, 187, 191)) {
        $output= substr($output, 3);
    }


$balanceJson = json_decode($output);
```

Comment: Updated my answer. I put some extra lines of code to remove hidden BOM characters

Answer (score 0):

Check your curl response. Do you have access to the code?

Create an array with data (code,description,status,balance) and then send it as output using `json_encode`. It looks like you are have some hidden characters in your string, because the length of visible characters is 75 and `var_dump` is showing a string with 114 charaters.